# Date regex, exclude issue

Tags: regex

I am new to regex and still learning. I am writing a regex to capture date from multiple pdf files. On the pdf files there are 2 dates mentioned in below format. I just want to capture First one and exclude Loss Date from my results. The regex I use is still capturing Loss Date. Can you please help me and let me know how can I exclude Loss Date?

Thank you

[image]

What I have tried:

```
(?:Date : )?(?:(?:[12][0-9]|0[1-9])[/.-]02|(?:30|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])[/.-](?:0[469]|11)|(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])[/.-](?:0[13578]|1[02]))[/.-][0-9]{4}
```

To exclude I tried

```
(?!\s*Loss Date)
```

Its still capturing Loss **Date : MM/DD/YYYY** part in bold. I want the regex to totall exclude Loss Date Data.

Comment: I guess you could just add `(?<!Loss )` to the beginning of your pattern

Comment: You are greatttttt. Thank you so much man. It worked. Solution Regex is (?<!Loss )Date : (?:02[/.-](?:[12][0-9]|0[1-9])|(?:0[469]|11)[/.-](?:30|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])|(?:0[13578]|1[02])[/.-](?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9]))[/.-][0-9]{4}

Comment: In this case, though it might not work in other situations (e.g. if there are invalid dates), I would greatly simplify your regex. Use `\d` to represent any digit. e.g. `\d\d/\d\d/\d\d` would match any date in the format you showed in the question. This would simplify your regex to something like this

`date\s+:\s+\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}`

also, note I used the {2} quantifier, which I see that you are already aware of.

Learn the `\s` and the other basics, like `+`. It will greatly simplify your regex patterns and encourage you to use them more frequently.

Comment: Unless you expect to get date-like strings in your source text that aren't dates, a simple negative lookbehind followed by something formatted like a date would probably be sufficient: `(?<!Loss Date : )\b\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}\b`.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. You are all so great and helpful. I am new and this was my first post here. Do I have to close this post by doing anything to show it resolved?

Comment: You can post an answer to this question (yes, even if you are the asker) and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone, These both regex are working. I dont see accept button to resolve this post here.

((?<=(?<!Loss )Date : )\d\d/\d\d/\d{4})

(?<!Loss )Date : (?:02/.-|(?:0[469]|11)/.-|(?:0[13578]|1[02])/.-)[/.-][0-9]{4}

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be the following.

```
((?<=(?<!Loss )Date : )\d\d/\d\d/\d{4})
```

This will match any *\d* which is preceded by *"Date : "*, which subsequently is not preceded by *"Loss "*.